# Consulta por firma digital en un documento xml con c#

Tags: c#, xml, firma-digital

Recurro a ustedes porque ya no se me ocurre dónde más buscar información.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual mis documentos **xml** tienen que llevar una firma digital. Para esto me pasaron un documento **xsd** para que, cuando genere mi firma, lo valide contra este. El tema es que por ahora es una firma digital simple, yo creo un certificado y se lo asigno al documento con el siguiente código (este código me lo pasaron por otra pregunta que había hecho antes acá):

```
private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument, string pathCert, string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
{
    XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
    documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

    SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

    var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
    firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
    firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

    //digest info agregada en la seccion firma
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
    reference.Uri = "#Documento101";
    firmado.AddReference(reference);

    reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

    firmado.AddReference(reference);

    // info para la llave publica 
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
    firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    firmado.ComputeSignature();

    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();

    // buscamos el ultimo elemento del documento
    XmlElement elemento = (XmlElement)documentXml.SelectSingleNode(@"//Document/Content/adu/TmstFirma[last()]");

    XmlNode parent = elemento.ParentNode;
    parent.InsertAfter(xmlDigitalSignature, elemento);
    documentXml.Save(pathXmlSignet);
}
```

Cuando se genera la firma su estructura es la siguiente:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
    <Reference URI="#Documento101">
    <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <DigestValue></DigestValue>
    </Reference>
    <Reference URI="#Documento101">
    <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <DigestValue></DigestValue>
    </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Y la que me están pidiendo es esta:

```
<SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="#Documento101">
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue></DigestValue>
    </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
    <KeyValue>
    <RSAKeyValue>
        <Modulus></Modulus>
        <Exponent></Exponent>
    </RSAKeyValue>
    </KeyValue>
    <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

El tipo de firma que estoy usando es **enveloped** eso lo tengo claro y lo uso con un certificado, pero no sé cómo buscar el tipo de firma que me piden acorde a esa estructura.

Si alguien me puede guiar o decirme a qué tipo de firma corresponde me ayudaría mucho.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebas solo elimina los elementos de transformacion, estos no son necesarios para
la verificacion de firma, tambien el contenido del agregar parte del certificado
puedes excluirlo, aqui el metodo con algunos elementos eliminados y agregada la parte
de RSAKeyValue

```
private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument,string pathCert,string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
    {


        XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
        documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

        SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

        var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
        firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
        firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

        //digest info
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        //reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        //reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference.Uri = "";


              reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

        firmado.AddReference(reference);

        // with the public key will be added in the signature part. 
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)cert.PrivateKey));
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

        firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;


        firmado.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();
        documentXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(documentXml.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        //guardando salida.
        documentXml.Save(pathXmlSignet);
    }
```

con esto obtienes una salida similar a lo que buscas:

```
 <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <Reference URI="">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>ooqJ2kDYWTdeb+nrSvsUYq7KNys=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>0Qp1N1+VPW594eI/AIgeKs2A6ZcglixEDrVPxCSCID0XXG2u8i2Xz4uGbYTcRvCvZWoG7wK7dAMc9nH8CZtnBgvQcF4EUYkuMU12wgGl2Gszk+0CM3rAJ3TGx5wpwfcWB97O7xJcxdWcE/ERPXXjR5gjXCl3KaVfbDuZTfj79/zHJvfUQjTA7DfsOSF4RxDsBg+ZWZbZNHarUIfEhqO3dAWfQSrvymtRNuRn1Z+arCgrTzhCKdQH4oan0In7+ap0RLfMrYVSE4nOjwbyc9ud11aD4ZMkKYP9oFbIPYlBI3z3kVp5k4pppWnLTJBACokmEujt+zGSWJhRD0//2baz7Q==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>4iM7/CK3bQmQn2bAWbN/nxj8jJIgV/AQBFFujeTq3frI+4eEJhtLPws6ATPrQT9kSgPViIZUyak3TJNhiZovrQ0uOXyxEqR8Z5W8Lza/dNzHYgcTjHE3hfc664hOH3YeIixllr09LFMEcwbVwJB7GnuRpy9lvxHKOtQ2E+3AVvjZRmonfBx+7+paAk5zE2U/yhePVTubww/+uxDGNToO+0ER4I+aQ8Tk4RDJl3SKt9YCYc5J0E4Er1MFlRunwFrSjKAg/mNxwYuumxDDzIpwFhi93KSOJHA2kQRqLOZgCtkJT3EVUeojAHY/0pvkC9CT5zUkcWGfTfqFkyXnsnnPmQ==</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
          </KeyValue>
          <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
```

Comment: Creo que tu la otra vez igual me ayudaste, muchas gracias. no sabía que había que eliminar esas transformaciones. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo pase por algo similar generando unas firmas para procesos de facturación electrónica (SAT, México) tengo dos soluciones

- La primera y que aun utilizo para un proceso fue "construir ese XML a
  mano" osea que voy creando partes del XML las firmo por separado y al
  final las agrego en uno solo tomando en cuenta, encoding en utf8,
  cuidando espacios en blanco y el como cierran los tags
- La segunda cambio totalmente ya que no podía construir el xml de la misma forma cuando a simple vista cumplía con la misma estructura mi
  solución fue un bloque de código similar al tuyo la diferencia es que
  yo no indico explicitamente el atributo Algorithm=""

---

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider oKey = oCSD.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;SignedXml oSigXml = new SignedXml(oDocXml) { SigningKey = oKey };
            Reference oReference = new Reference() { Uri = string.Empty };
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform oEnvelop = new  XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            oReference.AddTransform(oEnvelop);
            KeyInfoX509Data oKeyData = new KeyInfoX509Data(oCSD);
            oKeyData.AddIssuerSerial(oCSD.Issuer, oCSD.SerialNumber);
            KeyInfo oKeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            oKeyInfo.AddClause(oKeyData);
            oSigXml.KeyInfo = oKeyInfo;
            oSigXml.AddReference(oReference);
            oSigXml.ComputeSignature();
```

Comment: igual es buena tu solución pero como yo ya tengo todo armado, creo que no podría ordenar de nuevo el programa como me indicas jajaja. Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 0):

Al código de @Miguel Zárate, le tuve que agregar 2 transformaciones para que funcionara el envío de un sobre a la DGI (Uruguay).
Sin las transformaciones el error que obtenía era:
E04
Firma electrónica no es válida
No se ha podido validar la firma del CFE - Hash values do not match.

```
        /**
     * Con los parámetros recibidos:
     *   - nodo xml (XElement)
     *   - certificado de firma digital
     * Devuelvo:
     *   - nodo con la firma (XElement)
     */
    public static XElement GetFirmaNodo(XElement nodo, X509Certificate2 certificado)
    {
        SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(nodo.ToXmlDocument())
        {
            SigningKey = (RSA)certificado.PrivateKey,
        };
        firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

        // Agrego la referencia, con las transformaciones necesarias
        Reference reference = new Reference
        {
            Uri = "",
            DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
        };
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        
        firmado.AddReference(reference);

        // Agrego la información de la clave del certificado
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)certificado.PrivateKey));
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado));

        firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        firmado.ComputeSignature();

        return firmado.GetXml().ToXElement();
    }
```