# Incorrect reference digest value al procesar firma en XML

Tags: c#, xml, firma-digital

desde Uruguay les escribo, esta vez solicitando ayuda con un problema en C# y la firma de un documento XML, estoy teniendo el mensaje **"Incorrect reference digest value"** al intentar procesar el XML en la web del ente regulador DGI en mi país.

les pongo el documento y el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument, string pathCert, string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
    {
        XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
        //documentXml.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

        SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

        var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
        firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
        firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

        //digest info agregada en la seccion firma
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";
        reference.Uri = "";
        firmado.AddReference(reference);


        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

        KeyInfoX509Data kdata = new KeyInfoX509Data();

        X509IssuerSerial xserial;

        xserial.IssuerName = cert.IssuerName.Name;
        xserial.SerialNumber = cert.SerialNumber;

        kdata.AddIssuerSerial(xserial.IssuerName, xserial.SerialNumber);

        keyInfo.AddClause(kdata);
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
        firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        firmado.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();
        documentXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(documentXml.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        //guardando salida.
        documentXml.Save(pathXmlSignet);
    }
```

El documento original a firmar es:

```
    <CFE xmlns="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
   <eFact>
      <TmstFirma>2020-06-08T17:20:20</TmstFirma>
      <Encabezado>
         <IdDoc>
            <TipoCFE>111</TipoCFE>
            <Serie>A</Serie>
            <Nro>11</Nro>
            <FchEmis>2020-06-08</FchEmis>
            <FmaPago>1</FmaPago>
            <InfoAdicionalDoc>Si Corresponde</InfoAdicionalDoc>
         </IdDoc>
         <Emisor>
            <RUCEmisor>123456789012</RUCEmisor>
            <RznSoc>Pablo Alonso</RznSoc>
            <NomComercial>Infofarma</NomComercial>
            <GiroEmis>TiendaPlaza</GiroEmis>
            <Telefono>12345678</Telefono>
            <CorreoEmisor>infofarma@pesca.com.uy</CorreoEmisor>
            <EmiSucursal>Principal</EmiSucursal>
            <CdgDGISucur>4</CdgDGISucur>
            <DomFiscal>General Paz 1234 of 4</DomFiscal>
            <Ciudad>Montevideo</Ciudad>
            <Departamento>Montevideo</Departamento>
            <InfoAdicionalEmisor>Informacion adicional opcional</InfoAdicionalEmisor>
         </Emisor>
         <Receptor>
            <TipoDocRecep>2</TipoDocRecep>
            <CodPaisRecep>UY</CodPaisRecep>
            <DocRecep>219999830019</DocRecep>
            <RznSocRecep>MUNICIPIO LA PAZ</RznSocRecep>
            <DirRecep>AV. ARTIGAS ESQUINA RODO</DirRecep>
            <CiudadRecep>LA PAZ</CiudadRecep>
            <DeptoRecep>CANELONES</DeptoRecep>
            <PaisRecep>Uruguay</PaisRecep>
            <CP>11900</CP>
            <InfoAdicional>Informacion adicional</InfoAdicional>
            <LugarDestEnt>direccion de entrega de ser necesario</LugarDestEnt>
            <CompraID>1</CompraID>
         </Receptor>
         <Totales>
            <TpoMoneda>UYU</TpoMoneda>
            <MntTotal>193.8</MntTotal>
            <CantLinDet>1</CantLinDet>
            <MntPagar>193.8</MntPagar>
         </Totales>
      </Encabezado>
      <Detalle>
         <Item>
            <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
            <CodItem>
               <TpoCod>INT1</TpoCod>
               <Cod>123456</Cod>
            </CodItem>
            <IndFact>4</IndFact>
            <NomItem>BOLSA DE RESIDUOS ASURIN 70X95</NomItem>
            <Cantidad>1</Cantidad>
            <UniMed>N/A</UniMed>
            <PrecioUnitario>193.8</PrecioUnitario>
            <MontoItem>193.8</MontoItem>
         </Item>
      </Detalle>
      <CAEData>
         <CAE_ID>123456789</CAE_ID>
         <DNro>1</DNro>
         <HNro>100000</HNro>
         <FecVenc>2021-11-01</FecVenc>
      </CAEData>
   </eFact>
</CFE>
```

Y lo que estoy obteniendo luego del firmado es:

```
    <CFE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy">
  <eFact>
    <TmstFirma>2020-06-08T17:20:20</TmstFirma>
    <Encabezado>
      <IdDoc>
        <TipoCFE>111</TipoCFE>
        <Serie>A</Serie>
        <Nro>11</Nro>
        <FchEmis>2020-06-08</FchEmis>
        <FmaPago>1</FmaPago>
        <InfoAdicionalDoc>Si Corresponde</InfoAdicionalDoc>
      </IdDoc>
      <Emisor>
        <RUCEmisor>123456789012</RUCEmisor>
        <RznSoc>Pablo Alonso</RznSoc>
        <NomComercial>Infofarma</NomComercial>
        <GiroEmis>TiendaPlaza</GiroEmis>
        <Telefono>12345678</Telefono>
        <CorreoEmisor>infofarma@pesca.com.uy</CorreoEmisor>
        <EmiSucursal>Principal</EmiSucursal>
        <CdgDGISucur>4</CdgDGISucur>
        <DomFiscal>General Paz 1234 of 4</DomFiscal>
        <Ciudad>Montevideo</Ciudad>
        <Departamento>Montevideo</Departamento>
        <InfoAdicionalEmisor>Informacion adicional opcional</InfoAdicionalEmisor>
      </Emisor>
      <Receptor>
        <TipoDocRecep>2</TipoDocRecep>
        <CodPaisRecep>UY</CodPaisRecep>
        <DocRecep>219999830019</DocRecep>
        <RznSocRecep>MUNICIPIO LA PAZ</RznSocRecep>
        <DirRecep>AV. ARTIGAS ESQUINA RODO</DirRecep>
        <CiudadRecep>LA PAZ</CiudadRecep>
        <DeptoRecep>CANELONES</DeptoRecep>
        <PaisRecep>Uruguay</PaisRecep>
        <CP>11900</CP>
        <InfoAdicional>Informacion adicional</InfoAdicional>
        <LugarDestEnt>direccion de entrega de ser necesario</LugarDestEnt>
        <CompraID>1</CompraID>
      </Receptor>
      <Totales>
        <TpoMoneda>UYU</TpoMoneda>
        <MntTotal>193.8</MntTotal>
        <CantLinDet>1</CantLinDet>
        <MntPagar>193.8</MntPagar>
      </Totales>
    </Encabezado>
    <Detalle>
      <Item>
        <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
        <CodItem>
          <TpoCod>INT1</TpoCod>
          <Cod>123456</Cod>
        </CodItem>
        <IndFact>4</IndFact>
        <NomItem>BOLSA DE RESIDUOS ASURIN 70X95</NomItem>
        <Cantidad>1</Cantidad>
        <UniMed>N/A</UniMed>
        <PrecioUnitario>193.8</PrecioUnitario>
        <MontoItem>193.8</MontoItem>
      </Item>
    </Detalle>
    <CAEData>
      <CAE_ID>123456789</CAE_ID>
      <DNro>1</DNro>
      <HNro>100000</HNro>
      <FecVenc>2021-11-01</FecVenc>
    </CAEData>
  </eFact>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>zykXZOhDGWkWyOyUiddegY8osJg=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>qPjfpnySg4O/O7yCE+j43kseSQ6TRtM0OtalP2oQFlu1qwGEBjOE+HkqFSMaQeEzr3pONwL+OzcbCS1I5r/+FFNGjwT+NLZKa21J69qpfTxOGQcCWKaKROw3LsHgWL4mflCuDq/cajWMCogLLiuVQj1SdPfarhUQpj55cyCosQcxEEbfrSOcK1u7HmD0i1OFj25uy+EavUgfp473jdMUasjHL8y9BCoeQbPszyiscnuNaeXgHeDhKDD2TtnhuZzGvzOPJTk+cEVug2xU4WbuxWXjxxxsEJI7O4p5R+lYchAklwgmnQ7riN5RkRKK0MxxVfV7ZEa8G7SqFRnSkxt97Q==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509IssuerSerial>
          <X509IssuerName>CN=Abitab, OU=ID digital, O=Abitab S.A., L=Montevideo, C=UY</X509IssuerName>
          <X509SerialNumber>45467518827781355680696586257417759671317623631</X509SerialNumber>
        </X509IssuerSerial>
      </X509Data>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</CFE>
```

Me podrán ayudar ??? estoy muy perdido ya que esto de las firmas es super nuevo para mi, es de suma importancia poder recibir una ayuda de ustedes, gracias, gracias , gracias

Mil Gracias a todos.

Comment: te sirve esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276122/consulta-por-firma-digital-en-un-documento-xml-con-c?rq=1

Comment: No, cuando hago el computeSignature me dice "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Algoritmo especificado no es válido.",